# "Relative" class property referencing

Tags: java, list, class, parameters

I want to pass a "relative" reference of a class property as a parameter.

First of all, I don't know if "relative reference" is actually the proper name for this, but what I have in mind is something along these lines:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getAllPropertyValues(someObjectClass.someInteger) { //someObjectClass.someInteger being the "relative reference"
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (someObject x : someObjectList) {
        temp.add(x.someInteger);
    }
}
```

The idea would be to pass a reference to (for example) `Human.Age` and the method would add to the list each `x.Age`.

In other words, given an object `x` if I pass the property `y` i'd be able to call `someDataType recievedProperty = x.y`. Regarldess of which kind object is `x` or what type is `y`.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: Just clarifying, do you want this method to add the `Age` property of every instance of `Human` to the list?

Comment: Let me edit the question and make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you could use a `ToIntFunction` that accepts a SomeObjectClass and returns an `int`.

```
 public ArrayList<Integer> getAllPropertyValues(ToIntFunction<SomeObjectClass> function) { 
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (someObject x : someObjectList) {
        temp.add(function.apply(x));
    }
 }
```

And you could invoke it :

```
ArrayList<Integer> results = getAllPropertyValues(SomeObjectClass::getAge);
```

You could pass `getAge()` or any method of `SomeObjectClass` that returns an `int`.

Comment: That's actually, pretty much what I'm looking for! I'll check how to do it on a generic method!

Comment: There's no point in using a `ToIntFunction<SomeObjectClass>` instead of just `Function<SomeObjectClass, T>` with `T` being a generic type parameter of the method, as you are storing the `int`s in an `ArrayList<Integer>`, thus boxing the integers.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffne You are right. I confess to have hesitated for this same reason. But I finally kept like that as it gives me the feeling that it was more readable. Not really in fact ?

Comment: You are right, it is more readable this way. If you introduce a generic type parameter, the code will be less readable. On the other hand, I think the OP really wants a way to *project* a list of `SomeObjectClass` to a list of *any* type.

Comment: Alex Coronas and @Federico Peralta Schaffner  I will edit with a generic way for the returned List.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner In fact, what I wanted was to pass the generic type. The list of objects was just an example.

Comment: @davidxxx It's not necessary that you edit the answer. It's clear and understandable as it is.

Comment: This answer uses a *method reference*. To use a *field* of some class instance, you could use a *lambda expression*: `getAllPropertyValues(x -> x.age)`.